# Confusion with LiveData Observers, Adapters, Coroutines

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

Using MVVM Architecture.

I'm having trouble trying to figure out how I should be approaching this task. The idea is that I want to retrieve a list of songs from a REST API, pass that list into a SongListAdapter that uses the song list to create a custom recycler view, and then inflate that view.

Before it was as simple as

```
//Get Songs
        CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
            val songList = viewModel.getSongs()                  

            withContext(Main){
                val rvSongs = rvSongs as RecyclerView
                val adapter = SongListAdapter(songList)
                rvSongs.adapter = adapter
                rvSongs.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@SongListActivity)
            }
        }
```

But now I want to do this with liveData instead and `val songList = viewModel.getSongs()` doesn't cut it. Instead I need to use

```
viewModel.getSongs().observe(this@SongListActivity, Observer {
    //UI Stuff
}
```

The issue is that `getSongs()` hits an api endpoint to retrieve the list, which needs to be done on a background thread. But observers can't be invoked on background threads... Which makes me think the way I'm approaching this is all wrong.

I was thinking that I could have two different functions for getting songs... one that hits the endpoint and the other which converts the `List<Song>` data to a `MutableLiveData<List<Song>>` but that feels like I'm over-complicating it. How should I go about doing this with livedata?

SongListActivity

```
class SongListActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.song_list) //I changed this for testing, change back to activity_main

        //Set View Model
        val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(SongListActivityViewModel::class.java)

        //Get Songs
        CoroutineScope(IO).launch{
            //Need to hit getSongs() endpoint here

            withContext(Main){
                val rvSongs = rvSongs as RecyclerView
                val adapter = SongListAdapter(songList)
                rvSongs.adapter = adapter
                rvSongs.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@SongListActivity)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SongListActivityViewModel

```
class SongListActivityViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val songLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<Song>?>()

    //Returns list of songs on the first page.
    suspend fun getSongs(): MutableLiveData<List<Song>?> {
        //Hit Endpoint
        val songPage1 = FunkwhaleRepository.getSongs()

        //Store as LiveData
        songLiveData.postValue(songPage1.results)
        return songLiveData
    }
}
```

Comment: Curious why you're switching from coroutines to LiveData, when so many experts are recommending everybody start transitioning from LIveData to coroutines now that we have SharedFlow. There are a couple of errors in your example coroutine code, by the way.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Could you expand a bit on that? I've been following codingwithmitch on youtube and he's usually talking about using livedata in his older videos. I'm new to android dev so I don't know anything about SharedFlow.

Comment: SharedFlow is pretty new (like three months). It and its subclass StateFlow can be used as replacements for LiveData. The reason it's getting recommended these days is it helps break your repository and view model layers' dependency's on Android-specific tools. LiveData will probably be kept around for a while though, since coroutines and SharedFlow are Kotlin-only. But I think there's a chance LiveData eventually gets deprecated and Google tells all the Java developers, "Too bad, switch to Kotlin.".

Comment: That feels like something I should look into then! Recommend any useful beginner guides on the subject?

Comment: I can look and suggest something later. I think I just learned from the official documentation and a Medium post by Roman Elizarov.

Comment: All good, I'm sure I'll find some tutorials on the subject. Thanks!

Comment: Here's the explanation that helped most for me: https://elizarov.medium.com/shared-flows-broadcast-channels-899b675e805c And I'll mention, you don't have to use Flows over LiveData. The main motivation is something that won't really affect you if you aren't ever going to port your app to other platforms that can run Kotlin. I've transitioned mainly because I wanted to learn something new, and because I think there's a possibility LiveData gets phased out later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I think you should take a look at using proper Android lifecycle scopes to launch your coroutines. If you create a scope in an Android component like an `Activity` then you should look into cancelling it yourself when the activity is destroyed. There is some good documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines) which I would recommend taking a look at.

In regards to your actual question, you're on the right track!

First of all, your `ViewModel` should expose some `LiveData` as it does in your code but should launch a coroutine scope in its `init` block which fetches the data from the endpoint. Then when it has fetched it, you should only then set the `LiveData` value to your loaded data.

In your activity, instead of trying to launch a coroutine to setup your `RecyclerView`, set it up beforehand with just the `LayoutManager` and then start observing the exposed `LiveData`. Then when the data being observed is changed, only then set the adapter to the `RecyclerView`.

A quick pseudocode overview might help:

**ViewModel**

```
ViewModel {

    val liveData = MutableLiveData<>()

    init {
        scope.launch {
            liveData.value = api.fetch()
        }
    }
}
```

**Activity**

```
Activity {
    onCreate {
        ...
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager
        ...
        viewModel.liveData.observe {
            recyclerView.adapter = Adapter(data)
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** *You can also use the `liveData(LiveDataScope<T>.() -> Unit)` builder function to simplify the `ViewModel` code but I would recommend understanding both approaches and how they differ.*

Comment: For `scope`, I'd recommend simply using `viewModelScope` and keeping it on the main dispatcher. The OP's mistake in their original coroutine code is not using the `lifecycleScope` or `coroutineScope`, but rather creating a new scope that will leak the views if the fetching outlives the Activity.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I was just giving a structural overview as opposed to implementation details so I didn't mean 'scope' to be taken literally, in this instance `viewModelScope` would be the correct choice.

Comment: This approach worked for me! Thanks for giving me some pointers on some of the mistakes I was making!

Comment: @DazedFury No problem! Just a quick note about the mentions of `SharedFlow` etc. Using `LiveData` is perfectly suitable here as long as it stays in the presentation layer. Whereas if you were going to implement a repository pattern to fetch your data then you should use some implementation of `Flow`

Comment: @HenryTwist I actually might be using the repository pattern. When `viewModel.init()` is run to set the livedata, it's hitting `repository.getSongs()` which then hits `apiInterface.getSongs()` which uses retrofit2 to actually hit the endpoint. Should I look into implementing Flow in this case?

Comment: Flow is an observable data holder, so if you are making a one time request in the repository (which I think you are?) then you don't need to implement anything observable!

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question but what do you mean by one time request? I'm probably going to want to hit the request to retrieve new songs every time the user tries to refresh the page or something similar right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229433/discussion-between-henry-twist-and-dazedfury).

Comment: It may still be an appropriate pattern to use LiveData or SharedFlow, because then you can make the request immediately upon instantiating the ViewModel, and the Activity/Fragment can observe/collect it whenever and it might already be ready and waiting.